# Solve $2p+6=n^3$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

How can I prove that if $p$ is a prime, there is an unique solution for the equation

$$2p+6=n^3$$

where $n$ is an integer?

I know that $p=29$ is the solution, but I don't know how to demonstrate that is the only one. Anyone can help me?

Comment: I ask to the committee that applied the exam and found the correct problem: If $p$ is a prime, there is an unique solution for the equation $$2p+1=n^3$$, where $n$ is integer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not the only solution: $10973$ is prime and $2\cdot10973+6=28^3$.

Comment: I found this problem in a contest from 1996, sorry for putting something wrong.

Comment: how did you find this answer? By computer?

Comment: By hand. But I checked with Mathematica if 10973 is a prime and then found many more solutions.

Comment: Can you tell me some of the other solutions, please? I need to see some things with this equation.

Answer (score 7):

Motivated by Arentino's observation, here are some other solutions as provided by Mathematica 10 (all solutions for $n\le 1000$). They are listed in the form $\{n,p\}$.
Here's the code:

```
Do[If[PrimeQ[(n^3 - 6)/2], Print[{n, (n^3 - 6)/2}]], {n, 2 Range[500]}]
```

{4,29}

{28,10973}

{32,16381}

{44,42589}

{50,62497}

{58,97553}

{98,470593}

{128,1048573}

{148,1620893}

{154,1826129}

{172,2544221}

{182,3014281}

{224,5619709}

{242,7086241}

{254,8193529}

{268,9624413}

{274,10285409}

{280,10975997}

{302,13771801}

{322,16693121}

{358,22941353}

{394,30581489}

{428,39201373}

{442,43175441}

{452,46172701}

{508,65548253}

{518,69495913}

{568,91625213}

{574,94559609}

{592,103737341}

{604,110174429}

{610,113490497}

{620,119163997}

{694,167127689}

{722,188183521}

{728,192914173}

{730,194508497}

{760,219487997}

{764,222971869}

{784,240945149}

{788,244651933}

{802,257924801}

{812,267693661}

{814,269676569}

{830,285893497}

{938,412646833}

{994,491053889}